# devstack error: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)

Tags: openstack, devstack

I installed devstack successfully only on the first time.

Then, after running again ./stack.sh I get error:

```
2016-01-20 19:58:45.797 | + '[' -n 
/home/const/data/devstack/files/images/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-uec/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-vmlinuz ']'
2016-01-20 19:58:45.798 | ++ openstack --os-cloud=devstack-admin image create cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-uec-kernel --public --container-format aki --disk-format aki
2016-01-20 19:58:45.799 | ++ get_field 2
2016-01-20 19:58:45.800 | ++ local data field
2016-01-20 19:58:45.800 | ++ read data
2016-01-20 19:58:45.800 | ++ grep ' id '
2016-01-20 19:58:46.569 | The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-ed5f0f38-5798-4a52-8d1c-0d185ca8bb80)
2016-01-20 19:58:46.610 | + kernel_id=
2016-01-20 19:58:46.610 | + '[' -n /home/const/data/devstack/files/images/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-uec/cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-initrd ']'
2016-01-20 19:58:46.611 | ++ openstack --os-cloud=devstack-admin image create cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-uec-ramdisk --public --container-format ari --disk-format ari
```

Platform: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS @ PC

I've tried to remove directories and databases. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing following directories and run again.

```
~/.config/openstack
/etc/nova
/etc/keystone
/etc/cinder
/etc/glance
```

It may happen that the .conf files are not getting updated with the new install.